# 403 Forbidden Error while deploying a laravel website on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment, shared-hosting

I had a complete laravel project and I decided to deploy it. I bought a server and a domain and configured the server to be used by the domain. Then I compressed my local project and extracted it in a folder named `explore` in the root folder. I researched and copied the contents of public folder into a folder named `explore` in the `public_html` folder. Then, I changed the `index.php`'s line saying: `require __DIR__.'/../../explore/vendor/autoload.php';` and another line that says:
    `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../explore/bootstrap/app.php';`
as suggested by the blog posts which I found by searching **How to deploy a laravel website on shared hosting**. But I get an error saying

> 403
>   Forbidden
>   Access to this resource on the server is denied!

So, what might be the problem and what should I do to make this website up and running? For a note, The permissions of the `explore` and `public html` folder are `0777` and `0750` respectively. I guess the problems might be due to folder permissions, so what should I do to solve me this problem?

Comment: Check your server's error log to see if anything interesting shows up there.

Answer (score 1):

Have you changed `bootstrap/config/cache.php` contents? You need to change this file content before you actually run your project. In this file, you need to change all project paths and urls.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: And there is no cache.php page there as well!

Comment: If it exists then reconfigure it, else create one by this command: "php artisan config:cache" in your local environment then copy its content and paste in your host and then reconfigure.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give read and execute permission to other, so give `0755` to `public html` folder, it might resolve your issue.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work @Yogesh Salvi. What would you have done from step 1 to last if you had to deploy it. May be this way, I can get help!

Comment: Try giving permission recursively, are you able to access static assets like any css, js or images in browser from same domain?